# how to build a facebook signed_request string in python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

there is plenty of docs on how signed_request-s are build up, but could not find (and come up with) a simple method that creates a signed request

does anyone has a solution?

the basic docs are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/):

I would need it for unit tests. More precisely, I'm using [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk), and just wrote a nice middleware for using facebook authentication together with tastypie. To test this I need the mock the auth process of facebook, and the last missing step is to create the cookies set in the browser when the auth happens.

The result will be open sourced.

Answer (score 0):

Like following:

```
from hashlib import md5
def fb_signature(request, app_secret):
    fb_request = dict([(k,request[k]) for k in request if k.startswith('fb_sig')])
    payload = ''.join(['%s=%s' % (k[len('fb_sig_'):], fb_request[k]) \
                          for k in sorted(fb_request.keys()) if k != 'fb_sig' ])
    return md5(payload + app_secret).hexdigest()
```

Here *request* --- your request to calculate signature,  app_secret --- your FB app secret.

Comment: I need one for OBJ-C! It's hard to understand your code since I don't know python. Also, what is the content of request?

Comment: @JayQ. Your question tagged with "python" rather than Obj C. you should change the tags.

Comment: this wasn't my question :) I just ran into this post while looking for an Obj-C version of this code. :P

Comment: @JayQ. Have a look here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/